# Count up number of items in each section

Tags: counters

I have a numbers of sections and subsections that have continuous enumeration (i.e. if the first section stops at 4, the second section starts counting at 5). As given by the following:

```
\section{Section 1 (Number of Items in section: 3)}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
    \end{enumerate}
\section{Section 2 (Number of Items in section: 2)}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item Item 4
        \item Item 5
    \end{enumerate}
```

What I want to do is automate the part that says "Number of Items in section: x". Right now, I'm manually counting up the items, but is there a way to get the number of items in the following section and update it automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is quite an easy task with `xcntperchap` package (I am the author of this package, ok -- shameless promotion ;-))

The main purpose of this package is to count how many Y (here `enumi`) per track level counter X (here `section`) occur.

The basic usage is `\RegisterCounters{section}{enumi,...}`, the 1st argument is designed to hold the track level, i.e. the 'structure' level and the second argument holds a comma separated list of counter names, that should be tracked, here `enumi` (since this is the `enumerate` first level counter)

Multiple track levels are possible, just use `\RegisterCounters` for each of them, even the tracked counters can be used in multiple track levels, the 'book-keeping' is done behind and different track levels do not interfere!

The whole information is stored in a `\jobname.cpc` file and the information can be retrieved during the 2nd compilation run with

```
\ObtainTrackedValue[counter value]{section}{enumi}
```

The `counter value` specifies which section number should be tracked. Omitting it, the current value of the track level counter (here `section`) is used, which is quite convenient if one does not want to bother with the current section value.

The package is rather new and the successor of `cntperchap`, it's available on [CTAN xcntperchap](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcntperchap)

The `resume` feature of `enumitem` does have a negative side - effect, since `xcntperchap` uses `xassoccnt` in the background.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcntperchap}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\RegisterCounters{section}{enumi}

\begin{document}


\section{Section 1 -- with \ObtainTrackedValue{section}{enumi} items}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
    \end{enumerate}

\section{Section 2 -- with \ObtainTrackedValue{section}{enumi} items}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item Item 4
        \item Item 5
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing me to this package (and for writing it too!). This is exactly what I was looking for, and I wasn't expecting it to be so easy to implement. Thank you so much!

Comment: @pomegranate: Well, 'easy' in frontend, not so easy in the backend ;-) Happy TeXing!

Comment: Haha, of course! :) I appreciate your hard work on the backend! Quick question -- is there a way I can include these counted values in the Table of Contents? Right now, when I use \tableofcontents with headers similar to the ones you show above, the entries appear as "Section 1 - with () items" etc.

Comment: @pomegranate: No, not in this version. `\ObtainTrackedValue` isn't expandable, i.e. it does not survive the write-to-ToC process. I'll think, I can provide a workaround.

Comment: @pomegranate: I've got a solution, but it requires a new package version. I try to upload tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Christian! That's so kind of you! One other thing I noticed when I was using the package: if I register counters for sections and subsections, all the counters in the first sections (and its subsections) work as expected, but the counters for the subsections of all subsequent sections take on the values of the first section's subsections. I.e. If Section 1, Subsection 1 has 5 items, then Section 2, Subsection 1 will also be said to have 5 items (regardless of how many it really has). Not sure if this is really a bug, or if I'm just doing something incorrectly!

Comment: @pomegranate: A 'feature' (no, a stupid error ;-)) It's fixed and I uploaded it to CTAN, you can get the file also from my personal webpage, see the 'Posts' at the right side

Comment: Thanks Christian! I just tested the new command and it works great. I just have one final suggestion for the expanded command (future feature request for a rainy day?): As it stands, one has to label each section with its number, i.e. \ObtainTrackedValueExp[15]{subsection}{enumi}) for the 15th subsection, to get the correct value. If one wishes to add a subsection before this, then all numberings have to be changed. It would be useful for this to automatically get the value of the current subsection. Just a thought. :) Thanks again for this useful package and for all your helpful responses!

Comment: @pomegranate: Yes, I know about this issue -- this was the problem in the former package already. I'll have to think about a unique mapping of section etc. numbers

Comment: @pomegranate: In case you're still interested: I've uploaded a version to to CTAN which makes use of labels in order to use some specific section as tracking level etc, i.e. no need to use a specific section number etc.